# Java equivalent for C CRC16

Tags: java, c, crc16

I need to convert `C` CRC16 method to `Java`. The problem is I'm not that good with `C` and Bytes operations.

`C` code:

```
static const unsigned short crc16_table[256] =
{
 0x0000,0xC0C1,0xC181,0x0140,0xC301,0x03C0,0x0280,0xC241,
 ...  /* Removed for brevity */
 0x8201,0x42C0,0x4380,0x8341,0x4100,0x81C1,0x8081,0x4040
};

unsigned short crc16 (const void *data, unsigned data_size)
{
 if (!data || !data_size)
 return 0;
 unsigned short crc = 0;
 unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)data;
 while (data_size--)
 crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc16_table[(unsigned char)crc ^ *buf++];
 return crc;
}
```

And that's my attempt to convert it. Not sure if that's correct.

```
private static int[] table = {
    0x0000,0xC0C1,0xC181,0x0140,0xC301,0x03C0,0x0280,0xC241,0xC601,0x06C0,0x0780,0xC741,
    ...    // Removed for brevity
    0x4400,0x84C1,0x8581,0x4540,0x8701,0x47C0,0x4680,0x8641,0x8201,0x42C0,0x4380,0x8341, 0x4100,0x81C1,0x8081,0x4040
};

public static int getCode (String[] data){
    if (data.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int crc = 0;
    for (String item : data) {
        byte[] bytes = item.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff]; //this confuses me
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

**Question:**
Is my porting to Java correct?

---

**EDIT**:

Modified `crc16` working method (thanks to great answers):

```
public static int getCode(String data) {
    if (data == null || data.equals("")) {
        return 0;
    }
    int crc = 0x0000;
    byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

This returns Decimal value. And CRC16 code needs to be Hexadecimal. I used this method to convert to base 16. Do it with received `crc` like `dec2m(crc, 16)`:

```
static String dec2m(int N, int m) {
    String s = "";
    for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= m) {
        int r = n % m;
        s = r < 10 ? r + s : (char) ('A' - 10 + r) + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

For testing your results you could use [this site](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) (Thanks to @greenaps)

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @MohitJain, ouch, I'm sorry. All I need is to know whether I converted that method correct. It brings result but I'm not sure if it's working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translated the c code function call `crc16 (const void *data, unsigned data_size)` wrong.

```
public static int getCode (String[] data)
```

should be

```
public static int getCode (String data)
```

Moreover you can also see in the Wialon pdf that you need a `getCode (String)` and not a `getCode(String[])`.

Converting the received String to a byte array stands.

Comment: Well you can read that exactly in the wialon pdf. They tell as much. Please reread. After that tell what you should take as `String data` when you have `String command="#SD#180615;081206;1800;N;01800;E;NA;NA;8;NA;crc";`

Comment: Alright, now I got the point. I was thinking that it's needed to take every element separately but not the whole bunch as whole.

Comment: Please post your new getCode() function and show how you use it beginning with the String command i gave you. Tell the crc. We will check.

Comment: @greenapps : I agree with you for `String` vs. `String[]`, but there's still the `getBytes()` encoding question ...

Comment: Wialon is silent about the encoding. So that is of second concern.

Comment: `Calculated: crc16 = 58693`. That is the same value as delivered by the C code for that string.

Comment: Equal to 0xE545. Try this online service for our string: http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote looks good as said by Mohit Jain. But your function does thing differently than original C one : you take an array of String, while C code takes a void *, and a length in bytes. So if you use your conversion function to validate a string containing non ASCII characters between an UTF-8 and a Latin1 platform, it will give different result, because with Latin1, "éè" will give the 2 bytes `0xe9`, `0xe8`, while with UTF-8, you will get 4 bytes : `0xc3`, `0xa9`, `0xc3`, `0xa8` => your CRC function will give different results.

IMHO, you should stick to original code and only compute a CRC for a byte array. You could force always same charset (say UTF-8 for example), but it will still be hard to compare your results with the C implementation, and you would loose the ability to compute the CRC of a raw byte array (binary data).

Anyway, the only way to make sure that your implementation gives same results than original C one, is to take an arbitrary byte string (all bytes from 0 to 255 for example), pass it to the C routine on one side and to you java one on the other side and compare both CRCs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You see, the idea was to build a string request to server which consists of `#L#protocol_version;imei;password;crc16\r\n`. And this `crc16` should be received from array of values `protocol_version; imei; password`. So I assumed that those values are String. I might misunderstand something because I don't realize how `C` does the same with `void*`

Comment: @AnZ : I'm confident that protocol_version and imei will always be fine. But password can contain almost everything (even if I would **never** put a non ascii character in a password ...). For last point C uses void * here in the sense of a raw byte array.

Comment: and in case if `password` will always be String whithout any digits or non-ascii symbols? Just UTF-8 English letters. Does this case ensure that java method will bring the same result as C's one?

Comment: @AnZ Oups UTF-8 english letters does not sound very well !.. But yes, if you only use characters with code < 128, they will have same value for all common encodings. Anyway, I still advise you to take a byte array in that function and to have a higher level wrapper that take string arrays to build the byte array. Separation of concerns eases tests and maintainability :-)

Comment: `And this crc16 should be received from array of values protocol_version; imei; password`. No. Please reread the Wialon document.

Comment: @greenapps, from document: `Packet sample:
#SD#date;time;lat1;lat2;lon1;lon2;speed;course;height;sats;crc16\r
\n
In this case crc16 is calculated for the following part of the packet:
date;time;lat1;lat2;lon1;lon2;speed;course;height;sats;`
What did I understand wrong?

Comment: Well then show me how you would call your getCode(String[]) function from that.